# Can you choose a random List member from a collection based on properties of objects in said List?

Tags: c#, object, arraylist

I wrote a program to shuffle media in a folder because the media player I have, while it does support shuffling, doesn't remember what it already played so a lot of times I get repeats.  I wrote my own to ensure everything gets played at least once.  So anyway, I made an object to hold the video info:

```
namespace MediaShuffler {
  class Video {
    public string filepath {get; set;}
    public string filename {get; set;}
    public string filetype {get; set;}
    public string fullfile {get; set;}
    public bool played {get; set;}

    override
    public bool Equals(object checkobj) {
      if (!(checkobj is Video)) return false;
      return ((Video)checkobj).fullfile == fullfile;
    }

    public Video(string file) {
      fullfile = file;
      filepath = Path.GetDirectoryName(file);
      filename = Path.GetFileName(file);
      filetype = Path.GetExtension(file).ToLower();
      played = false;
    }

    public void Play() {
      if (!Utils.cfg.ContainsKey("mediaplayer.executable") || 
          !Utils.cfg.ContainsKey("mediaplayer.executable")) return;

      Process proc = new Process();
      proc.StartInfo.FileName = Utils.cfg["mediaplayer.executable"];
      proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Utils.cfg["mediaplayer.directory"];
      proc.StartInfo.Arguments = Utils.TokenizeArguments(GetTokens());
      proc.Start();
      played = true;
      proc.WaitForExit();
      OnVideoComplete(EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    private Dictionary<string, string> GetTokens() {
      Dictionary<string, string> tokens = new Dictionary<string, string>();
      tokens.Add("%filename%", filename);
      tokens.Add("%filepath%", filepath);
      tokens.Add("%filetype%", filetype);
      return tokens;
    }

    protected virtual void OnVideoComplete(EventArgs e) {
      EventHandler<EventArgs> handler = VideoComplete;
      if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
    }

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> VideoComplete;
  }
}
```

In the main part of the program, I iterate over the path passed to the program and build a List "playlist" of all the files in the folder that are videos.  I realize after I made the object that I actually don't know an efficient way to get a random List member where member#hasPlayed is false.  What I ended up doing was:

```
while (true) {
  int selection = new Random().Next(0, playlist.Count-1);
  videoPlaying = true;
  Write("[" + selection.ToString() + " / " + playlist.Count.ToString() + "] Playing " + playlist[selection].filename + " ...");
  playlist[selection].Play();
  while (videoPlaying) Thread.Sleep(500);

  playlist.RemoveAt(selection);
  if (playlist.Count == 0) {
    if (!repeatList) break;
    BuildPlaylist();
  }
}
```

It works, but I was hoping I could actually leverage the hasPlayed bool in some manner, so that adding it wouldn't be pointless lol.  I suppose since it works it doesn't matter, but I just was curious if it *was* possible to do.  Also I wasn't sure the best way to make the process "rest" while the media player was doing its thing; is sleeping the thread momentarily the right thing to do?

Comment: **never** create instances of `Random`in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way would probably be using [`Random`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netcore-3.1) and LINQ [`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netcore-3.1) to select only those you haven't played yet like so:

```cs
// Select all where played == false
var notPlayed = playList.Where(x => !x.played).ToList();

// Create random Index, ensuring it is no larger than the count of unplayed songs
// Also, try not to create a new instance of random every time
var randomIndex = new Random().Next(notPlayed.Count);

// Play song
notPlayed[randomIndex].Play();
```

As a note: Try not create an instance of `Random` inside a loop, instead try to create it once, and re-use it

---

Here are a few more pointers to generally improve your code, not necessarily pertaining to your question:

1. Try and use Framework built in things, like the [FileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo) class, which already has properties for `fileName` and `filePath` (`Name` and `Directory`( `DirectoryName` respectively). It'd be better to wrap it and use something like [`Path.GetExtension`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getextension?view=netcore-3.1) to return the file extension
2. Try and adhere to the C#/ .NET naming and style conventions (especially [names of type members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-type-members)) (you can take a look at [NET Core source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime) to see how MS does it)